# CupertinoDatePicker A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to add a row of cancel and done button above the CupertinoDatePicker inside the Container but however hit error, what could possible go wrong?

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column

```
String _selectedDueDate;
var formatter = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');

ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.today),
              title: const Text('Due Date*'),
              subtitle: _selectedDueDate
              onTap: () {
                showCupertinoModalPopup(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        height: 300.0,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children:  <Widget>[
                                FlatButton(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Cancel",
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () => {},
                                ),
                                FlatButton(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Done",
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () => {},
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            CupertinoDatePicker(
                              initialDateTime:
                                  DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 7)),
                              minimumDate: DateTime.now(),
                              mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                              onDateTimeChanged: (date) {
                                setState(() {
                                  print(date);
                                  _selectedDueDate = formatter.format(date);
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can wrap `CupertinoDatePicker` with `Flexible` 
code snippet

```
 Flexible(
        child: CupertinoDatePicker(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _selectedDueDate;
  var formatter = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.today),
        title: const Text('Due Date*'),
        subtitle: Text("$_selectedDueDate"),
        onTap: () {
          showCupertinoModalPopup(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: 300.0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
                            child: Text(
                              "Cancel",
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                          ),
                          FlatButton(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
                            child: Text(
                              "Done",
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => {},
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                          initialDateTime:
                              DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 7)),
                          minimumDate: DateTime.now(),
                          mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                          onDateTimeChanged: (date) {
                            setState(() {
                              print(date);
                              _selectedDueDate = formatter.format(date);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `CupertinoDatePicker` in a `Container` and set the desired `height`.